# Python: how to add a function to the body of smtp message

Tags: python, smtp

Im a newbie to python and having a problem.
I want to attach a function to the body of smtp message.
the function return result of information, I need those results in my body message so other can see it when they receive the email not sure how to do it.

Any help for this newbie would be great!!

Here my code:

```
import smtplib

# For guessing MIME type
import mimetypes

# Import the email modules we'll need
import email
import email.mime.application

# Create a text/plain message
msg = email.mime.Multipart.MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Greetings'
msg['From'] = 'test1@mail.com'
msg['To'] = 'test2@mail.com'

# The main body is just another attachment
body = email.mime.Text.MIMEText("""Hello, how are you? I am fine.
This is a rather nice letter, don't you think?""")
msg.attach(body)


# send via Gmail server
# NOTE: my ISP, Centurylink, seems to be automatically rewriting
# port 25 packets to be port 587 and it is trashing port 587 packets.
# So, I use the default port 25, but I authenticate. 
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost', 25)
s.starttls()
s.login(username, password)
s.sendmail('To', 'From', msg.as_string())
s.quit() 

if len(argument1) > 0:
    startThebootstrap.function (argument1, t.argument2 ())
```

The current body only accept text, i want to change this to obtain a function result.
Is this possible?

Im using argsparse to command the section i want, and the result appear on CMD, i want those result in my email.

I have a command which start the display of the result.

Comment: Could you add more detail.

Comment: Thank you for having a look, i just added more to it. @MA1

Comment: Please show the function and what it returns so that we can answer the question more directly.

Answer (score 0):

**1. You want to send some python objects (function arguments or results)**

A general way is to use a "serializer" to make objects (not functions) to strings.

```
import pickle # pickle is not a save serializer. you can build virusses with it.
string = pickle.dumps(object) # string can be attached to the email.
object = pickle.loads(string)
```

pickle can transport virusses and functions but these two can not:

```
import json
string = json.dumps(object).encode('utf-8') # string can be attached to the email.
object = json.loads(string.decode('utf-8'))

import ast
string = repr(["smile!"])
object = ast.literal_eval(string)
```

**2. you want to send the source code of a function**

```
import linecache
def function():
    return 5
source_lines = inspect.getsourcelines(function)[0]
source_code = ''.join(source_lines) # make the list to a string
```

now you can add `source_code` to the body of the mail.

Let me know of your ideas about this and whether you understand it.